Bzzzz noise on guitar pickup when I plug my computer to external battery power source
I have Jackery battery (220V, 500W) and I want to record my guitar with pickup (Dean Markley Pro Mag Plus Acoustic Guitar Single Coil Pickup) on my Focusrite Scarlett 18i20. When I turn on electricity on the battery, strange "bzzzz" noise is being heard.
I created video which clearly illustrates the issue: 


At 10:00 I turn on the battery but electric cable of my computer is not yet plugged into the battery. Some noise can already be heard even thought cables are not even connected. At 00:32 I plug in electric cable of my computer into the battery. The noise is overwhelming. It looks like some sort of interference to me.
ChatGPT pointed me toward power line noise filter but I am not sure if this is it. Should filter like this help?
I would like to record my music in the nature, that is why I am doing this.

Fir the first test in your video, when your computer is not plugged into the Jackery device, what happens if you use a power extension cord so your guitar, Focusrite, and computer are at least 6 feet away from the Jackery device?  Do you get the buzz at the same volume?

There is no interference if I move the battery 6 feet away. But if plug in electric extension cord into the battery and bring the cord near guitar pickup, electric field is again present.

I bought EMI filter. It helps a little bit, maybe 20% but this was not it.

My theory is that the Jackery box is contributing noise in two ways:  It's emitting magnetic fields that your guitar pickups are picking up, and its AC output voltage isn't as pure a sine wave as the documentation suggests. A magnetic field would explain why moving the box away from your guitar reduces some/most of the buzz.  And why the EMI filter doesn't help much.  Harmonics in the AC output would explain why there's buzz when your Focusrite and/or laptop are plugged into the box.  I don't have these devices in front of me to test, so all I can do is offer a theory.

@SottoVoce any idea how to figure out which power station would not cause such noise? Should we be careful about specific parameters when we are dealing with sound?

I ended up buying another guitar pickup and the issue was indeed resolved
